# Tkinter - checkbox with if statement

Tags: python, tkinter, checkbox

I would like to add a series of 3-4 checkboxes to my GUI. The data being displayed in my GUI would depend upon which combination of checkboxes the user selects. For example, if the user selects boxes 1 and 2, a specific piece of data would be displayed, but if the user selects 1 and 3, another would be displayed, etc.

How would I go about coding this? I know that variables can be assigned to the checkboxes. In my if statement, would I just do two conditions? For example,
if variable == 1 & variable == 2

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Roughly speaking yes, you need to confirm that the checkboxes are selected, e.g. in `PyQt` you would write `if checkbox01.isChecked() and checkbox02.isChecked(): display_data_xxx()`. What's probably confusing you is *when* to execute the code that does this. In a GUI, these interactions are constantly being monitored by the main GUI thread, but each GUI framework has their particular way of dealing with it. In `tkinter` this is done through events, so you'll probably need to read up on them.

Comment: You can bind all checkboxes events to one single function that checks for conditions.

Answer (score 1):

This is a project

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
root = tk.Tk()
var=IntVar()
var1=IntVar()
var2=IntVar()
checkbox = tk.Checkbutton(root, text="Value1", variable=var)
checkbox.grid(column=0, row=0)
checkbox1 = tk.Checkbutton(root, text="Value2", variable=var1)
checkbox1.grid(column=1, row=0)
checkbox2 = tk.Checkbutton(root, text="Value3", variable=var2)
checkbox2.grid(column=2, row=0)
def show():
    if var.get() == 1:
        if var1.get() ==1:
            lb=Label(root,text="Hello World").grid()
        if var2.get() ==1:
            lb=Label(root,text="Hello Python").grid()

bt=Button(root,text="Show",command=show).grid(column=0,row=1)
root.mainloop()
```

You can add a variable to check box with Int Var.If You sellect check box IntVar=1 and if you not sellect box IntVar=0.
So I have a project.If you sellect checkbox 1 and 3 it's create a label "Hello Python" and if you sellect checkbox 1 and 2 it's create a label "Hello World".